# Javascript get arguments of function in function literal

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

`idx.render` returns a *function*:

```
ƒ () { return artigos.crudButtons(true, true, false)}
```

best possible way to get the arguments of  `artigos.crudButtons(true, true, false)`.

I need and array with the *arguments* of `crudButtons`.

Thanks.

Comment: I M P O S S I B L E ( get the info from somewhere else ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it:

```
        var functionToText = '' + idx.render;
        var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var match = regExp.exec(functionToText);
        var crud = JSON.parse("[" + match[1] + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the arguments from your `ƒ ()` wrapper function. 
However, you *can* if you have access to the body of `artigos.crudButtons` using the special `arguments` array-like object.

Answer (score -1):

Lucky for you this is built in to javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments